# Counting each venue total

Tags: php, mysql, count

I've googled my heart out on this but cannot find anything that matches my query. I'm looking for something simple where I can count the total number of people attending a venue. The query below outputs each venue perfecting but as soon as I start using the COUNT(*) AS it doesn't display anything. I've now removed the count so you can see the working query.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM venues ORDER BY VenName ASC";
                $result = $link->query($sql1);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                $norows = ($result->num_rows);
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['VenName'] . " | " . $row['VenTime'] . "</td><td style='text-align: left;'>" . $row['VenCoach'] . "</td><td style='text-align: center;'><input type='checkbox' name='VenActive'>" . $row['VenActive'] . "</td> <td><a href='showVenue.php?VenID=" . $row['VenID'] . "'><i class='fas fa-eye' style='align:center;'></i></a> <a style='padding-left:10px;' href='showRegister.php?Venue=". $row['VenName'] . " | " . $row['VenTime'] ."'><i class='fas fa-table'></i></a></td></tr>";
                }
                    } else {
                    echo "No available venues";
                    }
                $link->close();
```

I've changed my query to reflect the join of the venue table and the children table that are registered to the venue and related by VenID. Although the query is not throwing up any errors it not displaying any rows either.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT venues.*, COUNT(children.VenID) AS cnt FROM venues JOIN children ON venue.VenID = children.VenID GROUP BY children.VenID ORDER BY VenName ASC";
                $result = $link->query($sql1);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                $norows = ($result->num_rows);
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['VenName'] . " | " . $row['VenTime'] . "</td><td>" . $row['cnt'] . "</td><td style='text-align: left;'>" . $row['VenCoach'] . "</td><td style='text-align: center;'><input type='checkbox' name='VenActive'>" . $row['VenActive'] . "</td> <td><a href='showVenue.php?VenID=" . $row['VenID'] . "'><i class='fas fa-eye' style='align:center;'></i></a> <a style='padding-left:10px;' href='showRegister.php?Venue=". $row['VenName'] . " | " . $row['VenTime'] ."'><i class='fas fa-table'></i></a></td></tr>";
                }
                    } else {
                    echo "No available venues";
                    }
                $link->close();
```

Comment: use **GROUP BY VenName** in your query. the you can also use **COUNT(*)**

Comment: Are you sure that the people attending a venue are stored in the venues table? I would have thought that the attendees would have a separate table.

Comment: You are right, I tried the GROUP BY VenName as advised by Bernd Buffen and it work in that it count the Venue (which was 1) I have now tried to join the other table which has the register people attending as shown above. Thanks both